# Getting SQL tuples that contain the largest value of an aggregate attribute after grouping

Tags: sql, count, group-by, aggregate

Here is the schema:

```
ACTOR (id, name)
PLAY (id, name, year)
CASTS (pid, aid, character)
```

The question is:
Find the plays with the largest cast (actors distinct) and return the titles and cast size of those plays.

This is SQL query that I have so far:

```
select mm.id, mm.name, count(distinct a.id) as numOfActors
from actor a
join casts c on c.pid = a.id
join play mm on mm.id = c.aid
group by mm.id, mm.name;
```

Every tuple returned from that query contains a different play, displaying its id, name, and the number of casts it has. But from there I'm having difficulty trying to fit it as a subquery within an outer query that would allow me to extract only the tuples that have the largest numofActors value (so like if the largest value was 100, then the only tuples that would be returned all have 100 actors).

Yeah this is one of those "homework"-type of problems, but I'm also looking for a conceptual understanding too (essentially, extracting the tuples that contain the largest value of a certain aggregated attribute after grouping has been done). Ordering by descending and selecting the top tuple doesn't work since there may be more than one tuple with the largest value.

Comment: What database are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the approach in SQL Server:

```
select acp.*
from (select p.id, p.name, count(distinct a.id) as numOfActors,
             max(count(distinct a.id)) over () as maxcnt
      from actor a join
           casts c
           on c.pid = a.id join
           play p
           on p.id = c.aid
      group by p.id, p.name
     ) acp
where numOfActors = maxnt;
```

The expression `max(count(distinct a.id)) over (partition by partition by p.id)` is an example of a window function.  It is calculating the maximum value of a field over a group of rows.  Because the `()` are empty (there is no `partition by` clause), this assigns the same maximum value to a new column in all rows.

What value is that?  It is the maximum of the calculated value `count(distinct a.id)) over (partition by partition by p.id)`.  You want to find all plays that have this number of actors, so the outer query just selects these.

A subquery is needed because you cannot use window functions in the `where` clause.

EDIT:

```
with acp as (
      select p.id, p.name, count(distinct a.id) as numOfActors
      from actor a join
           casts c
           on c.pid = a.id join
           play p
           on p.id = c.aid
      group by p.id, p.name
     )
select acp.*
from acp join
     (select p.id, max(numOfActors) as maxnoa
      from acp
      group by p.id
     ) acpm
     on acp.id = acpm.id and acp.numOfActors = acpm.maxnoa;
```

Comment: Would it be possible without using over()?

Comment: Yes, but that would require a subquery joined back to your expression or common table expression.  This is the simplest and generally most efficient way of writing the query.